# how to get the count of records in one table based on two date fields in another table

Tags: mysql

How to get the count of records in one table based on two date fields in another table

For example:
**table 1:leaves**

```
| leav_id     | from      | to             |


| 1           | 2015-10-20 | 2015-10-27    |

| 2           | 2015-11-10 | 2015-10-12    |
```

**table 2:holidays**

```
| holi_id     | On         | Name       |


| 1           | 2015-12-25 | Christmas  |
```

I want to get the `number days between from and to in table leaves excluding the count of holidays from table holiday in that range`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do , I have created some more holidays for doing the calculation

```
mysql> select * from leaves ;
+---------+------------+------------+
| leav_id | from       | to         |
+---------+------------+------------+
|       1 | 2015-10-20 | 2015-10-27 |
|       2 | 2015-12-20 | 2015-12-30 |
+---------+------------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from holidays ;
+---------+------------+----------+
| holi_id | on         | name     |
+---------+------------+----------+
|       1 | 2015-12-25 | X-Mass   |
|       2 | 2015-12-26 | Saturday |
|       3 | 2015-12-26 | Sunday   |
|       4 | 2015-10-24 | Saturday |
|       5 | 2015-10-25 | Sunday   |
+---------+------------+----------+
```

So the following query will give you total number of leaves which is excluding the holidays

```
select 
t1.leav_id,
( 
  datediff(t1.`to`,t1.`from`) 
  - 
  sum(
    case when t2.`on` >= t1.`from` and t2.`on` <= t1.`to` 
    then 1 else 0  end
  ) 
) as total_leave
from  leaves t1 
left join holidays t2 on t2.`on` >= t1.`from` 
and t2.`on` <= t1.`to` 
group by t1.leav_id
```

The result will be as

```
+---------+-------------+
| leav_id | total_leave |
+---------+-------------+
|       1 |           5 |
|       2 |           7 |
+---------+-------------+
```

Also note that, `datediff` function may not give you correct result, ex

```
mysql> select datediff('2015-12-30','2015-12-20') as d ;
+------+
| d    |
+------+
|   10 |
+------+
```

Here its 10 days, however when the leave is calculated its 11 i.e. from `2015-12-20` till `2015-12-30`

So need to re factor the above query to add `+1` as

```
select 
t1.leav_id,
( 
  datediff(t1.`to`,t1.`from`) 
  - 
  sum(
    case when t2.`on` >= t1.`from` and t2.`on` <= t1.`to` 
    then 1 else 0 end
   ) 
 )+1 as total_leave
from  leaves t1 
left join holidays t2 on t2.`on` >= t1.`from` 
and t2.`on` <= t1.`to` 
group by t1.leav_id
```

And will give as

```
+---------+-------------+
| leav_id | total_leave |
+---------+-------------+
|       1 |           6 |
|       2 |           8 |
+---------+-------------+
```

Comment: That perfect. But how can i avoid saturdays and sundays without adding them in the holiday table? Anyway thanks abhik

Comment: You mean you want `saturdays and sundays` should be excluded from the list but they are not in holidays table ?

Comment: Yes. Want to exclude Saturdays and Sundays from the total leave count. Without adding the dates to holiday table.

Comment: That will be very difficult if not impossible. I will need to check if this could be used in the above way within the query or not before giving you any advice.

Answer (score 0):

First use `datediff` :-

```
select datediff(to, from) as day from leaves
```

Answer (score 0):

I have edited my answer, Can you please try this way.

```
SELECT l.*, 
datediff(l.`to`, l.`from`) as leavedays,
IF((SELECT h.holiday FROM holidays AS h WHERE h.holiday between l.`from` AND l.`to`)<>'',1,0) AS holyday,
(datediff(l.`to`, l.`from`)-(SELECT IF(count(h.holiday)='',0,count(h.holiday)) FROM holidays AS h WHERE h.holiday between l.`from` AND l.`to`) AS totalday
FROM
leaves AS l
```